# How does Laravel protects itself from html injection?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

Hello I'm new to laravel and I tried to add HTML to a `<h6>` field like below image .[image: 1]

and it appears in the page source like this

[image: source]

My question is why it doesn't render in the browser ? What has Laravel done here ?

My Blade code :

```
   @extends('layouts')

<div class="row">
    <div class='col-md-6 offset-md-3'   >
    @section('content')
    <h1>{{$card->title}}</h1>

    {{$card->created_at}}


    <br>
    <ul class="list-group">
    @foreach($card->notes as $note)

    <li class="list-group-item">
        <h6>{{$note->body}}</h6> <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" onclick="togglediv('divform{{$note->id}}')" >Edit</button>

        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3" id="divform{{$note->id}}" style="display: none;">
    <hr>
<form action="/notes/{{$note->id}}/edit" method="POST">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  {{ method_field('PATCH') }}
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1"><h6>Edit the note</h6></label>
    <input type="text-area" name="body" class="form-control" id="body" placeholder="{{$note->body}}">
  </div>


  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Done</button>
</form>
</div>


    </li>


    @endforeach


<script type="text/javascript">function togglediv(id) {
    var div = document.getElementById(id);
    div.style.display = div.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none";
}</script>






    </ul>
</div>
</div>
@endsection

@section('footer')

<br>
<div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
    <hr>
<form action="/cards/{{$card->id}}/notes" method="POST">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1"><h3>Add a new note</h3></label>
    <input type="text-area" name="body" class="form-control" id="body" placeholder="Body">
  </div>


  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Note</button>
</form>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: it has escaped your html, you need to use {!! !!}

Comment: @madalinivascu I added {!! !!} to the code sample but it still escapes html ,

Comment: can you paste the code?

Comment: @madalinivascu  https://imgur.com/a/Ke8Jc please check

Comment: This isn't your source code you are showing on image, it is already rendered outcome. Show us your source code. Also, if it's not variable, it shouldn't be in {!! !!}.

Comment: @sskoko I edited the question

Comment: laravel does what is said to be `html tag filtering`

Comment: I guess so , so there is no way I can inject html here ? @chandlerbing

Comment: If this is complete code, you are missing many closing tags.

Comment: No this is the relevant part ,I ll update with full code  , @sskoko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html is escaped ,if you don't want that use the following syntax to output the html

```
  {!!$note->body!!}
```

more [info](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#displaying-data)

Comment: I edited the question with the code  , please note I'm trying to inject html to the form field to update the field .

Comment: @lasan can you tell me what type of input this is `<input type="text-area"`?

Comment: Thanks , oops it should be textarea right , I'm using bootstrap anyways , couldn't see a difference even though it was wrong .

Comment: so in default , Laravel filters all tags?

Comment: @lasan yes all outputs in `{{}}`